# Collapsing duplicates to a single row in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe

[image: A snapshot of the dataframe]
I am required to calculate the time between game starts and game overs for each user. But there are a lot of dulicate events at relatively short time intervals, therefore I want to calculate the time event between the first game_start and last game_over event. I thought I could partitionBy user_id and then create a sliding window of two and find the difference, but I am new to Scala and can't seem to be able to implement. Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @spakr val result = paly_event
  .withColumn("lagValue", coalesce(lag(col("name"), 1).over(window), lit("")))
  .where(
    (col("name") !== "lagValue")
  )
  .drop("lagValue") But as I told in the question , I am new to Scala and not very proficient in the same and not able to figure out. I usually do things in python/pandas and could have dropped duplicates by shifting by one  and comparing but cant figure out things in scala. Moreover as I read and understood partitionBy can't be used in dataframes in Scala. like this